# Missing <gtkmm/eventcontrollerkey.h> header file after installing gtkmm

Tags: c++, gtk, gtkmm

I've been using gtkmm for a while now and haven't had any problems. I recently wanted to start using `Gtk::EventControllerKey` for some event-handling goodies, but `make` was telling me that it couldn't find that class. I looked at the docs, and it said it should be included in `<gtkmm/eventcontrollerkey.h>`, which should have been covered in my `<gtkmm/gtkmm.h>`, but I tried it anyways.

When that header file wasn't found, I checked the include folder for `gtkmm`, and I could only find the `<gtkmm/eventcontroller.h>`. After looking around, the `EventControllerKey` class is definitely part of `gtkmm`, so I checked the Github page, and lo and behold, the header was there.

I'm running Ubuntu 20-something and I have `libgtkmm` version `3.24.2-1build1` installed.

I can't figure out why I don't have this. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

[gtkmm Github](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gtkmm/-/tree/master/gtk/src)

[GTK EventControllerKey](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/unstable/GtkEventControllerKey.html)

[gtkmm EventControllerKey](https://developer.gnome.org/gtkmm/stable/classGtk_1_1EventControllerKey.html)

Comment: You could maybe try to reinstall it?

Comment: Been there, didn't work. Looks like the version in the package repository and the most up-to-date version on the Github page are different.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your version of Gtkmm is too old. You mention that you have version 3.24.2 installed. Looking too fast at the Gtkmm [official repository](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gtkmm), one could conclude that the header `eventcontrollerkey.h` simply exists. However remember that this view is for the branch master, which is ahead of 3.24.2.

In your case, if we select the repository tag for version 3.24.2, we
get [this view](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gtkmm/-/tree/3.24.2),
in which the header is indeed not available.

In fact, we have to go as far as [version 3.95.1](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gtkmm/-/tree/3.95.1) to see it (in 3.93.0, which is the closest available tag, it is not there). This makes sense according to the [documentation for `Gtk::EventControllerKey`](https://developer.gnome.org/gtkmm/stable/classGtk_1_1EventControllerKey.html#details)
which states that it (`Gtk::EventControllerKey`) is available from version 3.94 onward.

What is confusing is that in Gtk, `GtkEventControllerKey` is available from 3.24 onward, as described [here](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/unstable/GtkEventControllerKey.html), under the description section. In this case, Gtkmm is (a bit) behind Gtk.

In conclusion, if you want to use this, you are going to have to update to version 3.94 or higher.

Comment: Yup. Basically, last I knew, `gtkmm` maintainers don't want to add API until at least a minor version bump, but they're not going to do that bump until GTK does, i.e. until/if GTK 3.26 and hence `gtkmm` 3.26 ever emerge. I'm not sure this is a 100% ideal policy, but it's what we have.